# Unable to locate the resource in Windows Phone SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-8-emulator

I am trying to do the setup for Windows Phone development in my System.I have updated my system with Windows 8 64 bit.Installed Visual Studio 2010.After that i have downloaded the Windows Phone SDK  .Now when i am trying to install that in my system it is showing me the error that

**Unable to locate package source**

This is the screen shot of the error

[image: Error ScreenShot]

So please help me and suggest me what is the problem in my system .how could i resolve this issue .Thanks for the help

Comment: I wasted quite a bit of time on this problem myself :( Hope my KB link helps you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok that you have 2010 installed. From the [SDK download page](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471), "The Windows Phone SDK provides a stand-alone Visual Studio Express 2012 edition for Windows Phone"

The bug you are running into is a known issue for x64 systems and one I ran into myself even with VS 2012 installed. I wrote about it in a [blog post a few days ago] and the solution is described in [KB2897627](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2897627).

Note: they've actually updated the KB in recent days; the solution used to be a bit more involved.

Comment: see i have searched on some sites they are saying that 2012 is required for Windows 8 Phone development

Comment: what should i do now can you suggest me will be thank full to u

Comment: You can download the full offline ISO at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=257234&clcid=0x409 (the Windows Phone 8 SDK includes VS 2012 Express)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem so i just checked for the updates of my OS, and updated the OS(windows 8) and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the comments: [Try the Express versions (at the bottom of the page)](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products)

They don't support ALL features like the Ultimate does, but it gives you the opportunity to program for WP7.x and 8 for free.

Answer (score -1):

i alway download my installation,  i am actualy curious as to what this problem is , i had the same error this morning, so i uninstalled everything and reinstalled everything and it seemed to work!

EDIT :
CHANGING MY ANSWER :

Very sorry to say, but the SDK only works with VS 2012  not vs 2010 
[SEE HERE](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35471)

Comment: i have done this twice from the last 2 days ..still the same issue

Comment: oh lovely, a downvote ... i just shared what worked for me and i get a down vote... ill help google the issue i also like to know what can cause this

Comment: so what i do should i again do that ..re installation of the Visual Studio and Windows SDK

Comment: Editid my answer, it ports with VS 2012 express, cant use it on VS 2010

Comment: so i have 2010 with me so it's not possible with that.and if not from where i will get 2012

Comment: you will have to go see Microsoft.com to see how you can obtain a free VS 2012 copy to run windows phone, i bought mine in the stores so i have no idea where to download such a copy.

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/en-za/download/details.aspx?id=30678   
is one link i found, dunno if it will work though :)